# Question about a block positive semidefinite matrix.

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite

Somebody could tell me if this result is true?

$\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    A & B \\
    B^T & C \\
  \end{array}
\right)$ is positive semidefinite if and only if 
$\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    HAH^T & HB \\
    B^TH^T & C \\
  \end{array}
\right)$ is positive semidefinite, for arbitrary H.

Comment: One direction is obvious from taking $H=I$.  I'm curious, what inspired the question?  Also could you please make explicit that you are talking about matrices with real entries?  Do you know that if $A$ is a positive semidefinite real matrix and $X$ is a real matrix, then $XAX^T$ is positive semidefinite?

Comment: I'm working with covariances matrices, and right now, I have a matrix in this form $\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    HAH^T & HB \\
    B^TH^T & C \\
  \end{array}
\right)$. I create some numerical experiments in MATLAB, and it looks like is true, but I cannot prove it. I tried to find some references, but nothing.

Comment: Yes, I know that. In fact, my issue is to prove that $C-B^TH^T(HAH^T)^\dagger HB$ is positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If $Y$ is a positive semidefinite real matrix and $X$ is a matrix, then $XYX^T$ is positive semidefinite (when the sizes make sense).  You can apply this with $Y$ your block matrix and $X=\begin{pmatrix}H&0\\0&I\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: GREAT. Thank you so much!